# Getting the entire cell information with Beautiful Soup/Web Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to web scrape this table of weapon stats from the game Final Fantasy XIII (https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_XIII_weapons). How can I put in a list the entire content of each cell? My code is like:

```
summary = soup.find('div',{'class':'mw-content-ltr mw-content-text','id':'mw-content-text'})
tables = summary.find_all('table')
data = []
rows = tables[0].findAll('tr')

for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    
    for td in cols:
        text = td.find(text=True)
        print(text)
        data.append(text)
name = []
rank = []
strenght = []
magic = []
exp = []
acquirement = []
dismantle = []

index = 0

for item in data:
    if 'EXP' in item:
        dismantle.append(data[index+2])
        acquirement.append(data[index+1])
        exp.append(data[index])
        magic.append(data[index-3])
        strenght.append(data[index-4])
        rank.append(data[index-5])
        name.append(data[index-7])
    index += 1
```

it's working fine for the cells that have a single data inside the `<td>`, but for entries in which the `<td` have multiple tags formatting the content, it only grabs the first piece of data on the cell.

For example, in `strenght[0]` the value I got is `15` when it should be `15 (Min) 115 (Max)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the line:

```
text = td.find(text=True)
```

by

```
text = td.get_text()
```

and you will get all the text inside the cell, e.g. `15 (Min) 115 (Max)` in place of `15`

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could also utilize Pandas to get the table and then if needed work with a dataframe to get the data you're wanting.

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_XIII_weapons'

tables = pd.read_html(url)
table = tables[0]

print (table.to_string())
```

**Output:**

```
print (table.to_string())
                                                    0     1                 2                 3                             4                 5              6                                                  7                                                  8
0                                           NameLevel  Rank          Strength             Magic               Passive Ability   Synthesis Group      EXP for ★                                        Acquirement                                          Dismantle
1                              Blazefire SaberLv.1-26     3   15(Min)115(Max)   15(Min)115(Max)                             —  Physical Defense     24,600 EXP       Buy: Up in Arms(2,000 gil)Initial: Lightning           Level ★: Spark Plug (x13), Tungsten Tube
2   A weapon new to the Sanctum army, this gunblad...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
3                                   FlambergeLv.10-61     5   68(Min)323(Max)   68(Min)323(Max)                             —  Physical Defense    449,310 EXP       Catalyst: Perovskite on Blazefire Saber Lv.★  Level ★: Iridium Plug (x18), Electrolytic Capa...
4   The barrel and frame of this weapon have been ...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
5                               Omega WeaponLv.47-100    11  302(Min)620(Max)  302(Min)620(Max)                        ATB +1       Independent  1,308,252 EXP          Catalyst: Trapezohedron on Flamberge Lv.★  Level ★: Spark Plug (x71), Tesla Turbine (x35)...
6   This upgraded gunblade maintains the propertie...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
7                                   Axis BladeLv.1-21     5     8(Min)48(Max)     8(Min)48(Max)            Attack: ATB Charge             Boost     66,750 EXP  Buy: Plautus's Workshop(15,000 gil)Find: Palum...               Level ★: Spark Plug (x7), Perovskite
8   Designed for ease of movement in the field, th...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
9                                   EnkindlerLv.13-41     9   49(Min)133(Max)   49(Min)133(Max)         Attack: ATB Charge II             Boost    287,154 EXP            Catalyst: Adamantite on Axis Blade Lv.★  Level ★: Iridium Plug (x12), Cobaltite, Axis B...
10  Remodeled to suit the mobility needs of specia...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
11                              Omega WeaponLv.39-100    11  132(Min)315(Max)  132(Min)315(Max)  Attack: ATB Charge II,ATB +1       Independent  1,433,256 EXP          Catalyst: Trapezohedron on Enkindler Lv.★  Level ★: Iridium Plug (x51), Mobius Coil (x45)...
12  This upgraded gunblade maintains the propertie...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
13                               Edged CarbineLv.1-26     3     8(Min)83(Max)   20(Min)170(Max)                             —     Magic Defense     33,000 EXP    Buy: Up in Arms(4,600 gil)Find: Gapra Whitewood          Level ★: Polymer Emulsion (x13), Actuator
14  This gunblade was developed as part of a proje...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
15                              Razor CarbineLv.13-61     5   46(Min)190(Max)  112(Min)448(Max)                             —     Magic Defense    438,360 EXP         Catalyst: Perovskite on Edged Carbine Lv.★  Level ★: Ferroelectric Film (x18), Liquid Crys...
16  A product of research into magically adept bio...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
17                              Omega WeaponLv.47-100    11  104(Min)210(Max)  352(Min)723(Max)                        ATB +1       Independent  1,308,252 EXP      Catalyst: Trapezohedron on Razor Carbine Lv.★  Level ★: Polymer Emulsion (x71), Crystal Oscil...
18  This upgraded gunblade maintains the propertie...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
19                                   LifesaberLv.1-21     5     8(Min)88(Max)     8(Min)88(Max)                Improved Raise            Low HP     70,850 EXP  Buy: Plautus's Workshop(20,000 gil)Find: Palam...         Level ★: Polymer Emulsion (x7), Perovskite
20  An officer's gunblade. Boosts HP restored to a...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
21                                 PeacemakerLv.16-41     8  100(Min)225(Max)  100(Min)225(Max)             Improved Raise II            Low HP    237,000 EXP             Catalyst: Scarletite on Lifesaber Lv.★  Level ★: Ferroelectric Film (x12), Perovskite,...
22  A commander's gunblade. Boosts HP restored to ...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
23                              Omega WeaponLv.37-100    11  205(Min)520(Max)  205(Min)520(Max)      Improved Raise II,ATB +1       Independent  1,461,537 EXP         Catalyst: Trapezohedron on Peacemaker Lv.★  Level ★: Ferroelectric Film (x51), Superconduc...
24  This upgraded gunblade maintains the propertie...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
25                                     GladiusLv.1-26     4   25(Min)175(Max)    13(Min)88(Max)                             —  Physical Defense     54,800 EXP      Buy: Up in Arms(7,100 gil)Find: Pulse Vestige              Level ★: Spark Plug (x13), Carburetor
26  The design of this gunblade is based on that o...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
27                             Helter-SkelterLv.19-61     6  154(Min)448(Max)   64(Min)190(Max)                             —  Physical Defense    334,656 EXP                Catalyst: Uraninite on Gladius Lv.★  Level ★: Iridium Plug (x18), Transformer (x12)...
28  Reverse engineered from an ancient pulse weapo...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
29                              Omega WeaponLv.42-100    11  317(Min)723(Max)   94(Min)210(Max)                        ATB +1       Independent  1,388,607 EXP     Catalyst: Trapezohedron on Helter-Skelter Lv.★  Level ★: Spark Plug (x71), Supercharger (x35),...
30  This upgraded gunblade maintains the propertie...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
31                                     OrganyxLv.1-26     2   37(Min)187(Max)   37(Min)187(Max)                  Leadenstrike          Adamancy     20,100 EXP                  Buy: Gilgamesh, Inc.(280,000 gil)               Level ★: Spark Plug (x13), Millerite
32  Manufactured for anti-Pulse operations, this p...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
33                                 ApocalypseLv.14-61     4  128(Min)410(Max)  128(Min)410(Max)                    Ironstrike          Adamancy    233,872 EXP                Catalyst: Cobaltite on Organyx Lv.★  Level ★: Iridium Plug (x18), Millerite (x2), O...
34  Sacrificing mobility for power, this imposing ...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
35                              Omega WeaponLv.33-100    11  281(Min)750(Max)  281(Min)750(Max)            Ironstrike, ATB +1       Independent  1,514,535 EXP         Catalyst: Trapezohedron on Apocalypse Lv.★  Level ★: Iridium Plug (x61), Credit Chip (x56)...
36  This upgraded gunblade maintains the propertie...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
37                                 HauteclaireLv.1-26     4   13(Min)138(Max)   13(Min)138(Max)                  Stagger Lock           Gestalt     54,800 EXP  Buy: Gilgamesh, Inc.(20,000 gil)Find: Mah'haba...            Level ★: Ceramic Armor (x13), Cobaltite
38  Merely a replica of an ancient weapon, this gu...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
39                                   DurandalLv.19-61     6  126(Min)378(Max)  126(Min)378(Max)                  Stagger Lock           Gestalt    334,656 EXP            Catalyst: Uraninite on Hauteclaire Lv.★  Level ★: Chobham Armor (x18), Cobaltite (x2), ...
40  A symbol of honor, the ceremonial blade is bes...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
41                              Omega WeaponLv.42-100    11  305(Min)711(Max)  305(Min)711(Max)          Stagger Lock, ATB +1       Independent  1,388,607 EXP           Catalyst: Trapezohedron on Durandal Lv.★  Level ★: Ceramic Armor (x61), Credit Chip (x56...
42  This upgraded gunblade maintains the propertie...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
43                                   LionheartLv.1-21     6     8(Min)68(Max)     8(Min)68(Max)                 Quick Stagger           Gestalt     63,060 EXP      Buy: Plautus's Workshop(28,000 gil)Find: Eden             Level ★: Ceramic Armor (x7), Uraninite
44  Once the weapon of a l'Cie, this gunblade allo...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
45                              Ultima WeaponLv.15-41     8   83(Min)213(Max)   83(Min)213(Max)                 Quick Stagger           Gestalt    227,448 EXP             Catalyst: Scarletite on Lionheart Lv.★  Level ★: Chobham Armor (x12), Uraninite, Lionh...
46  Used to strike down weakened foes, this gunbla...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
47                              Omega WeaponLv.35-100    11  183(Min)508(Max)  183(Min)508(Max)          Quick Stagger,ATB +1       Independent  1,488,630 EXP      Catalyst: Trapezohedron on Ultima Weapon Lv.★  Level ★: Chobham Armor (x51), Electrode (x45),...
48  This upgraded gunblade maintains the propertie...   NaN               NaN               NaN                           NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! Pretty clean solution of yours, I'll consider Maaz answer as the correct since it was the proper correction to my code, but I'll keep your suggestion too

Comment: After testing both methods, I liked more this one... is it the most common way to scrap tables?

Comment: If I see or am trying to parse ‘<table>’ tags, I go with this, pandas, first. MOST of the time it’ll get me what I want, or at the very least very little manipulation/data cleaning. But you can still learn a lot about how to iterate through the tags by doing it with tables, th, tr, td tags to get an understanding. But really once you understand it, it’s just quicker with pd.read_html(). The only time it won’t work is if you can’t access the html source without headers.